# One step in proof of intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am not getting one step in the proof of intermediate theorem from Lang's A first course in Calculus.

> **Theorem:** Let $a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function which is non-constant. Assume $f(a)<f(b)$ and take $\gamma$ such that $f(a)<\gamma < f(b)$. Then there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=\gamma$.

*Proof:* (1) Take $S=\{ x\in [a,b] \,:\, f(x)\le \gamma\}$. Then $S\neq \phi$ and bounded above by $b$. Let $c=\sup S$.

(2) If $f(c)<\gamma$ then, for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$, by continuity at $c$ we get $f(x)<\gamma$; pick-up one such $x$ close to $c$ and greater than $c$. Then $f(x)<\gamma$ with $c<x$ implies $c$ is not supremum of $S$, contradiction.

(3) If $f(c)>\gamma$, then again by continuity of $f$, for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ and with $x<c$, we have $f(x)>\gamma$. **This contradicts the fact that $c$ is supremum of $S$.**

**Q.** It could be very simple, but I was not getting the statement (contradiction) stated in bold face above. Can one explain this?

After step (2) in the book, I thought that the author will consider another set $T=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)\ge \gamma\}$ and proceed in similar way, but it was not the case. He used same set $S$ but for the case $f(c)>\gamma$, he arrived contradiction, and I was not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sequence point-of-view, there exists a sequence inside $S$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=c$. But by construction, $f(x_n)\le γ$, so by continuity of $f$ 
$$
f(c)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)\le γ.
$$
A contradiction.

---

Or as it is intended, for every $\epsilon>0$ you find a $\delta>0$ so that $f(x)>f(c)-ϵ$ for $x\in(c- δ,c]$. Now select $ϵ$ such that $f(c)=γ+2ϵ$. Every $x\in S\cap (c- δ,c]$ now provides a contradiction, and that set can not be empty, as $c$ is a limit point of $S$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)>\gamma$ for $x>c-\delta$, then $c-\delta$ is an upper bound of the set $S$, and so certainly $c$ cannot be the supremum.

Comment: Here $f(x)>\gamma$, and for $S=\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)\le \gamma\}$; I was confusing here, how to make use of $x$?

Comment: This means that all the values of $x$ between $c-\delta$ and $c$ are *not* in $S$.

Comment: Sorry; $f(x)>\gamma$, so $x$ can not be in $S$, right? Then is $x$ bigger than all members of $S$?

Answer (score 0):

It is a contradiction because you have found a smaller upper bound, and you already had that $c$ was the smallest one.